# Putting Image and Text Next to Each Other

Tags: html, css

I've looked through some of the posts on this site in regards to my question, but I seem to be encountering problems while using the solutions.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div align="left"><div id="imgleft"><img src="tradecurrencymain.png" /></div></div>
<p>There's two different trade types: a market order and a limit order.</p>
<p>A market order allows a trade to be excuted immediately using the current trading ratio; 16 tokens equals 1 coin and 1 coin equals 15 tokens. A limit order gives you more cotrol; you can choose how much coins/tokens you will receive. For example, you may want to trade 100 tokens for 95 coins - someone has to accept the trade though.</p>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#imgleft {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 30px;
```

If someone could explain how to get an image and text directly next to each other, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could do this : http://jsfiddle.net/9ynpn0o4/2/ . Or even could use the tables.

Comment: Would that align the text to the right though?

Comment: That would wrap the text around the image. If you float the image to left, the text has no choice but to fill the right. You can Google: Align text to the right, or wrap text around the image.

Comment: I've tried that, but now my div id 'imgleft' doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Please check the included URL. There is no imgleft div in the url I posted in the comment.

Comment: I understand that, but after using the code from your jsfiddle and 'imgleft', 'imgleft' doesn't work.

Comment: if you need the div then simply put them inside the same div. Both the P and img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tL3smcfq/2/).

I wrapped everything in a wrapper (`wrapper`) and then floated '`imgleft`' left. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="imgWrap" align="left">
<div id="imgleft">
    <img src="https://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/31/93/43/400_F_31934352_QzlwTKN58UqGWtVEaSBvgOPqvfYxrIb7.jpg" />
</div>
<p>There's two different trade types: a market order and a limit order.</p>
<p>A market order allows a trade to be excuted immediately using the current trading ratio; 16 tokens equals 1 coin and 1 coin equals 15 tokens. A limit order gives you more cotrol; you can choose how much coins/tokens you will receive. For example, you may want to trade 100 tokens for 95 coins - someone has to accept the trade though.</p>
```

CSS

```
#imgleft {
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put the text-align attribute inside the img tag:

```
<img align="left" src="tradecurrencymain.jpg" style="margin-right:30px;margin-left:30px;" />
<p>There's two different trade types: a market order and a limit order.</p>
<p>A market order allows a trade to be excuted immediately using the current trading ratio; 16 tokens equals 1 coin and 1 coin equals 15 tokens. A limit order gives you more cotrol; you can choose how much coins/tokens you will receive. For example, you may want to trade 100 tokens for 95 coins - someone has to accept the trade though.</p>
```